# Console log for Chrome DevTools API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am extending Google Chrome with the "chrome.devtools.panels.create" API, it means that I have now some logic in my browser by which I need to debug.

Is there anyway to see the Console log / Debug my DevTools additions?

Comment: I know you can do `Ctrl Shift J` (keyboard shortcut for Console) to open a new dev tools window on an existing dev tools window. See if that helps.

Comment: `Ctrl Shift J` indeed helps, thanks!

Comment: damn! this trick used to work, and the last chrome update disables it.

Comment: Still works for me. Opens a new dev tools window on the existing dev tools

Comment: Great, this indeed helps - so to conclude 1. detach window 2. F12

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is `console.log` you can wrap it up. Actually it works for any other function, not just `console.log` but here's example for wrapping `console.log`:

```
console._log = console.log;
console.log = function(){ 
    // you can do whatever you want with arguments, output to div, alert / etc.
    return console._log.apply(console,arguments); 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to eval a script in the inspectedWindow:

`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('console.log("test")')`